# Stored procedure error PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_HTTP' must be declared

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that request some XML data from a service. I have found several examples on-line and all of them point to using this UTL_HTTP package. However, every time I tried to compile my store procedure with that I get the error:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_HTTP' must be declared
```

Here is the basic skeleton of the code I want to use.

```
PROCEDURE GET_XML_DATA2 AS

BEGIN
   DECLARE
   v_soap_request    VARCHAR2(32767);
   v_soap_response   VARCHAR2(32767);

   v_http_request    UTL_HTTP.req; --Fails here
   v_http_response   UTL_HTTP.resp; -- Fails here too
   v_action          VARCHAR2(4000) := '';

BEGIN

    null;

END;

END GET_XML_DATA2;
```

It fails in the indicated lines and does not compile. I am using Oracle Express Edition and I have already tried to grant my user execute rights to that package. It did not work. 
What else can I look at? What else could be causing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you already figured out yourself, this seems to be a permission problem. Your user does somehow not have access to the UTL_HTTP package. Make sure your user has the EXECUTE permission on the package:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.UTL_HTTP TO my_user;
```

Note that you might have to do this as SYS.

Using SQL Developer (which I can recommend if you're doing PL/SQL development), see if you can then look at the package somehow. If that does not help, please post the permissions that your user currently has.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I could not (still cannot) log-in as SYS. I tried logging in as SYSTEM and executed your command GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.UTL_HTTP TO my_user. It did not work and gave me this error: Error starting at line 1 in command:
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.UTL_HTTP TO spotfire
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM dba_objects WHERE object_name='UTL_HTTP'` return? Although I think that UTL_HTTP should exist in your database... Maybe it is not available in XE?