# Grant UTL_HTTP permission in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, reserved-words, settings

I would like to get HTML content from a certain webpage in my function. I read I can do it with the UTL_HTML package in PLSQL. So I made the following code in the project:

```
v_webcontent := utl_http.request(v_weblink);
```

Here the v_webconent and v_weblink are declared earlier. running this in de function gives an PLSQL exception: `PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_HTTP' must be declared`I guess this problem is because the package isn't available (from this link: [same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369834/stored-procedure-error-pls-00201-identifier-utl-http-must-be-declared)).

I followed the advice. So I created a new database connection in sql developer as the SYSTEM role (SYS didn't work, it sayd I could only logon using SYSDBA or SYSOPER but both wouldn't take the standard password I created with the database). Then I entered the code in the link above.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.UTL_HTTP TO [database];
```

The user I created is named 'Database'. It first gave me an error without the [] square brackets. Table or view does not exist so I then put the brackets around it. Now it gives error:

```
    Error starting at line : 1 in command -
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.UTL_HTTP TO [database]
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00987: missing or invalid username(s)
00987. 00000 -  "missing or invalid username(s)"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So I have no idea how to fix this. In the link above OP said that he got an other error, so I also checked if I didn't have the same problem. I entered:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_objects WHERE object_name='UTL_HTTP'
```

It returned 4 entry's. With owners: SYS, SYS, PUBLIC and APEX_040000.

Can somebody help me? Do I need to logon as SYS and with what passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log on as `SYS AS SYSDBA`.
2. Execute `grant execute on sys.utl_http to "Database";` **Do not** use any square brackets!

That should work.

**Piece of advice:** Do not name your DB user 'Database'.

---

**To reset your SYS password**

1. Run `cmd.exe` as administrator.
2. `cd` to your `${ORACLE_HOME}/database`.
3. Find the `PWDsomething.ora` file there (where `something` will be your instance name), copy its name (into clipboard).
4. Run `orapwd file=PWDsomething.ora password=SomePasswordOfMine force=y`, where `PWDsomething.ora` will be replaced with the file name from the step 3 and `SomePasswordOfMine` must be replaced by whatever password you wish to have.

That might work.

Comment: I made a new user with a different name. Now I tried to grant persmission using: 'grant execute on sys.utl_http to myuser;' because the user I'm using I didn't use the quotation marks. In both cases it gives me table or view does not exist. I'm on SYSTEM still because I can't seem to find a password for SYSDBA nor did I ever set it, do you know how I can get there passwords back?

Comment: @Politiepet, answer edited, try it. (I never had to reset my SYS password, so don't know if this will work.)

Comment: I already fixed it. The problem was not that I couldn't log into SYS. It was that the correct password didn't work for SYSDBA in sql developer. So what I did was on my sql server computer: opened cmd-typed in 'sqlplus/nolog', than 'connect sys as sysdba', password is stock password. From here I could run 'grant execute on sys.utl_http to "Database";' It worked this way.

Comment: Yup, `sqlplus` is always the best way. It would be my next advice to you if that password changing wouldn't work for you. :-) Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 5):

Since 11g you also have to create an access control list ('ACL') which specifies which users have access to particular domains, **it is no longer sufficient to just grant users execute privileges on utl_http!**

Something like this should work in 11g(after granting execute privileges on UTL_HTTP to your database user, as specified by the accepted answer) :

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl=>'mikesacl.xml',
  3  description=>'access control list example',
  4  principal=>'HR',
  5  is_grant=>TRUE,
  6   privilege=>'connect');
  7  commit;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


    SQL> begin
      2  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
      3  acl=>'mikesacl.xml',host=>'*'); 
      4  commit;

      5  end;
      6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Here is a very helpful link which explains the parameters of the above two functions :

http://www.oracleflash.com/36/Oracle-11g-Access-Control-List-for-External-Network-Services.html

Good luck!